# install my WebService on Windows-2000

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-2000

i Created `Web-Service` using C# on Visual-Studio 2008

and i force hem to work with `Frame-Work 2.0`

when i try to install this Web-Service on Windows-2000 i got this message:

```
This setup requires the .NET Framework version 3.5 (and Windows-2000 don't support Frame-Work 3.5)
```

how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.0 of the framework will install on Windows 2000 but Framework 3.0 and 3.5 will not.

> Version 3.5 supported OS

- Microsoft Windows XP
- Microsoft Windows Server 2003
- Windows Vista
- Windows 7,8

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Windows 2000 does not support .NET 3.5 framework. But there is a way to overcome it and it is given on this [website](http://rainstorms.me.uk/blog/2008/03/12/microsoft-net-framework-35-in-windows-2000/).